# amazon native shopping ads vs adblock

Tags: wordpress, adblock, affiliate, native-ads

On my Wordpress site which is affiliating with Amazon associate, i have many native shopping ads for products, that normally displays the products pictures with their names and the prices.

Lately, i activated ublock origin on my browser, then i realized there is only a white space in place of the products, at first i thought it was only due to slow internet, then i said maybe it is the cache so i deleted the cache, but nothing changes .... it took me a while to realize that ublock is killing all my native shopping ads.

which means this was going on for a while and i never noticed. maybe that is why the low click through, even that i have a good number of visits!

without adblock, my site look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H3wa.png)

after adblock, it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v12YX.png)

how can i fix this? is there any workaround it?

I searched in google and i found about asking visitors to disable adblock. that won't do, because it makes them suspicious of the site and usually just leave it.

I know i can put a picture of the products then write information on it with affiliate text link, but that won't give me the same design and usability as amazon's native shopping ads.

So, is there any way that i can make my amazon native shopping ads visible even with adblocking activated? some WordPress plugin or something?

Your help is highly appreciated, I really need this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an easy way to do this. Those are ads and users with adblockers want ads blocked.

You can try building your own system that delivers the ads and hope that adblockers do not adjust their filters, but that'll probably mean playing whack-a-mole: you change things, they adapt, you change them again, they adapt again.